# jQuery: create array with all unique values of a table

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, each

is there a way I can create an array using jQuery / JS that contains all unique values from a table, i.e. without duplicates ?
Also, the values I would be interested in are only in TDs with a certain class (`myClass`) + I would like to exclude "" and " " as non-valid values.

In the below example the output should be `[item1,item2,item3]` as the only unique and valid values.

**Example table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 1</th>
            <th>Vol 1</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 2</th>
            <th>Vol 2</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 3</th>
            <th>Vol 3</th>
            //...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="myClass">item1</td><td>8</td><td class="myClass">item2</td><td>7</td><td class="myClass">item1</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="myClass">item3</td><td>5</td><td class="myClass">item2</td><td>7</td><td class="myClass">item2</td><td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="myClass">item3</td><td>1</td><td class="myClass">item1</td><td>5</td><td class="myClass">item3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My JS so far (not covering duplicates):**

```
var result = new Array();
$('td').each(function() {
    if( ($(this).text() != '') && ($(this).text() != ' ') {
        result.push(+($(this).text()));
    }
});
alert(result);
```

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Objects are well suited for this since they can only contain unique keys.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what I have to change here ? I am pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array) to remove duplicate values from an array.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The filter solution in your link looks great. Do you know if this is also supported in IE8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = new Array();
$('td').each(function() {
    if( ($(this).text() != '') && ($(this).text() != ' ') {
        if(result.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1){
            result.push(+($(this).text()));
        }
    }
});
alert(result);
```

Comment: I think I'll go with this one as it seems to work in all browsers. If I would like to consider only TDs with a certain class would I just say $('td.myClass')... ?

Comment: Thanks. Using td.myClass only returns NaN for all the values.

Comment: Ok, I got this to work. I had to change the result.push line as follows: result.push( $(this).text() );

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.unique()` after:

```
result = $.unique(result);
```

or check beforehand:

```
if(result.indexOf(this.textContent) == -1){
    //push
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is $.unique supported in IE8 and IE9 ?

Comment: Yes if you use jquery 1.x, can't guarantee with 2.x onwards haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this but it does not remove the duplicates in my case.

Comment: That's odd did you do it after the each()?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var result = new Array();

$('#myTable').find('td.myClass').each(function () {
   if (result.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1) {
       result.push($.trim($(this).text()));
   }
});
console.log(result);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ghh9/)

---

With `$.inArray()`:

```
var result = [];

$('#myTable').find('td.myClass').each(function () {
   if ($.inArray($(this).text(), result) == -1) {
      result.push($.trim($(this).text()));
   }
});
console.log(result);
```

#### [With jQuery.inArray()](http://jsfiddle.net/2ghh9/1/)